# Working with Redis to store Session - Django

Tags: django, redis, django-sessions, django-redis

I have installed [`django-redis-session`](https://github.com/martinrusev/django-redis-sessions) via `pip` and add this settings to the `settings.py` file:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'redis_sessions.session'
```

When I go to the terminal and type:

```
$ redis-cli monitor
```

I can see there are changes when I log in and log out (using [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth)).

My question is: How can I get the session (from redis) based on the user?

If I call `is_authenticated()` User's function it works, but my DB's (PostgreSQL) Session table has 0 rows.

Fianlly, is there any way to write the session key and data manually? I will need to use a complex PK for session based in two fields stored in redis.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why would you expect any rows in Posgres? You've specifically set the session backend to redis.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, I don't expect rows in Postgres I was just saying that session has been succesfully stored in redis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get the current session with `request.session`. This should work, whichever session backend you use, whether or not the user is logged in.

See the docs on [using sessions in views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views) for more info.

Comment: From `request.session` I can access to user, thanks.

Comment: If you need the logged in user, then use `request.user` - you shouldn't have to go via the session.

Comment: Thanks again, one more question: Do you know how can I write the session manually? I need to use a complex PK for sessions and I'd like to store this in redis.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'write the session manually'. You can store values in the session with `request.session['key'] = 'value'`. If you are trying to change the session key, then I'm not immediately sure how you would do that, and I don't think it's a good idea anyway. Session keys should not be guessable.

Comment: I will take a look. Thanks again!